# Describing or using String to Explain a UIColor

Tags: swift, uicolor

Trying to simplify my implementation of coloring of each cell row object.
This is how I currently add a color to the object in each row:

```
progressViewLeft.primaryColor = Colors.Stage1
```

"Colors" is a struct set up like so:

```
struct Colors {

static let Stage1     = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
static let Stage2     = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

I'm looking for a way to instead of writing: "Colors.Stage1" and on the next one: "Colors.Stage2" something like this:

```
progress.primaryColor = String("Colors.Stage" + String(indexpath.row))
```

Comment: Have you tried with Array? you can use array.
progress.primaryColor = yourArray[indexpath.row]

Comment: It's impossible to assemble variable names at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
let allColors = [ UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) ,
                  UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)]
```

Then

```
progress.primaryColor = allColors[indexpath.row]
```